# Ошибка при запуска spring boot проекта

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

```
[![ошибка][1]][1]


package ua.com;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import ua.com.security.AuthenticationTokenFilter;
import ua.com.security.EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)//PreAuthorize
@ComponentScan("ua.com.*")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired 
    private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler entryPointUnauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetails;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetails);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.entryPointUnauthorizedHandler).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/auth/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() throws Exception{
        AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }


}
```

2018-01-30 22:49:23.629 ERROR 20337 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetails'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-01-30 22:49:23.645  WARN 20337 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Comment: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userDetails in ua.com.SecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.